# Plain/Empty page style for multipage ToC with package fancyhdr

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, fancyhdr

(edit) Added MWE at the end of the question.

Maybe it has something to do with redefining \thepage?
If so, I don't know how to make sure otherwise that all pages other than ToC, \chapter and \part are in the new fancyhrd style.

---

I am trying to get rid of the `fancyhdr` header (including the page number in my definition) for my table of content, which is 3 pages long.

I've already tried multiple related answers, but none of them seem to work in my case. For example, I tried:

```
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\let\ps@fancy\ps@emptystyle
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\endgroup
```

suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144797/hide-header-of-table-of-contents-in-latex), but it doesn't seem to do anything.

I also tried:

```
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
```

suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2995/removing-page-number-from-toc), which works in removing the `fancyhdr` header from page 1 and 3 of the ToC, but not the second.

Any idea what else can I try to get this working?

---

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, final]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[L]{\textit{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}} 
\fancyfoot{} 

\fancypagestyle{plain}{ 
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot{}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}

\setcounter{page}{0}

\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ans why not `\pagestyle{empty}` just before `\tableofcontents`, then`\pagestyle{fancy}`?

Comment: @Bernard: At least for `book.cls` `\tableofcontents` uses `\chapter*{\contentsname}`, meaning `\thispagestyle{plain}` is used right at the start of that comment, I fear `\pagestyle{empty}` would have no effect there! But as the document class is not known here, my comment is guessing only and you may be right

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: That's why I didn't post any answer.

Comment: @Bernard: Nor will I do...

Comment: Please post a compilable document that has this issue.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Added MWE, as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can load package [tocbasic](https://ctan.org/pkg/tocbasic), then you can use

```
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\addtotoclist[report.cls]{toc}
\renewcommand*{\tableofcontents}{\listoftoc[{\contentsname}]{toc}}% ToC under control of tocbasic
\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\thispagestyle{empty}\pagestyle{empty}}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\clearpage}
```

[image]

Note that `tocbasic` can not be used together with `tocloft`.

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, final]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\setlength\headheight{13.6pt}% as suggested by fancyhdr
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[L]{\textit{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}} 
\fancyfoot{} 

\fancypagestyle{plain}{ 
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot{}}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\addtotoclist[report.cls]{toc}
\renewcommand*{\tableofcontents}{\listoftoc[{\contentsname}]{toc}}% ToC under control of tocbasic
\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\thispagestyle{empty}\pagestyle{empty}}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\clearpage}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}% use a different numbering scheme to avoide the same identifier problem
\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to work.
Just to be sure: I don't need to use the previous `\thispagestyle{empty}` and `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}` anymore, right?

Comment: Yes, you do not need these additional lines anymore.  The suggestion uses hooks provided by `tocbasic`.

Comment: Thanks! (also for fixing the warning issues). Will mark as answered.